# Perl: Setting up environmental variables without touching code

Tags: perl, shell

I have a perl file that want to understand certain environmental variables. So I can add:

```
$ENV{PLACK_ENV} = 'development'
```

in the code and its ok.

But is there a way to do this without touching the code?

ps: I'm working with linux

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you can set environment variables without using Perl ?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes. I do not want to touch the perl code because i have 2 sets of environmental variables, for development and deployment. So I dont want to have things like "$ENV{PLACK_ENV}='development'" inside the code.

Comment: You can easily set environment variables within your shell. Inside your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily

```
$ export PLACK_ENV=development
$ perl your_script.pl
```

or

```
$ PLACK_ENV=development perl your_script.pl
```

Comment: Thanks @Taras that certainly works but what if I work with modules? Say A.pm needs development and B.pm needs A.pm. If I run A.pm as PLACK_ENV=development perl A.pm and then run PLACK_ENV=development perl B.pm, B does not get the environmental variables.

Comment: Sorry, B.pm does get them!

Comment: yw! Anyway, if you do `export PLACK_ENV=development`, all scripts and their modules you run in current shell will see this env variable. If you don't want to export this variable each time, you can just put that line to your `~/.bashrc` ( as recommended above ).